# centos 7 mdadm raid 1 error,

Tags: centos, raid, mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I am trying to get RAID 1 using mdadm. But I got the following error.

```
[root@localhost ahmed]# mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sd[a-b]1
mdadm: /dev/sda1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
       size=3907016704K  mtime=Thu Jan  1 04:00:00 1970
mdadm: Note: this array has metadata at the start and
    may not be suitable as a boot device.  If you plan to
    store '/boot' on this device please ensure that
    your boot-loader understands md/v1.x metadata, or use
    --metadata=0.90
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
       size=3907016704K  mtime=Thu Jan  1 04:00:00 1970
Continue creating array? n
mdadm: create aborted.
```

I am using two drives of 4TB. I used them before in RAID 1 using the motherboard hardware. Now I want to use them using mdadm.

I before using mdadm. I formatted them with GPT partition table and EXT4 file system.

Please advice me. And thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to add the file system *after* you create the array with mdadm.

The mention of ext2fs is actually just referring to the ext4 file system you created.

Also I would use `--level=1` instead of `--level=mirror` if you want RAID1.

Comment: How can I remove the file system and I will create it after creating the array?

Comment: @darking050, mdadm prompts you to continue `Continue creating array?`.  When you proceed it will destroy the filesystem and create the array.  Run `mkfs.ext4` on the md0 raid array after you're done.

Answer (score -1):

This could be a "bad sign", I'm not sure...

But in **our case** the device "/dev/sdc1" was having problems as we could see with the command...

`fsck -c /dev/sdc1`

**TIP:** If you are not worried about the contents of the disk use the `fsck -y /dev/sdc1` command so that all corrections will be made automatically if necessary.

You can use the command below to check for array failures (RAID)...

`echo check > /sys/block/mdXXX/md/sync_action`

... use the command below to track process progress...

`watch cat /proc/mdstat`

... and also the command below to check for errors (values above 0 indicate errors)...

`watch cat /sys/block/md125/md/mismatch_cnt`

**CONCLUSION:**

As we speak the error that you indicated seems to be a bad sign, so it is best to dismiss the drive (disk) that has problems and use another.

Thanks! **=D**

Comment: This is so wrong I don't even know where to start. Please do not answer RAID and filesystem related questions unless you really know what is going on.

Comment: The command `fsck -c /dev/sdc1` will check the filesystem including aspects like BAD BLOCKS. The command `echo check > /sys/block/mdXXX/md/sync_action` will check the created array ("RAID", colloquially speaking). I don't know what kind of knowledge you believe have, but unfortunately your comment and downvote do nothing for the OP. Effectively the explanations I present do not endanger the OP data.

Comment: Additionally, you can help by guiding with comments by providing links to relevant content or by trying to answer something. People need much more help than criticism. Think about that.